# Get missing numbers from mysql database between two numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, numbers

I'd like to get the missing numbers from a mysql database between two numbers. The range is from 0000000001 to 9999999999. In my table I have two columns `serial_start` and `serial_end`. In the first row, values are 100 and 500 and in the second row, 501 and 9999999999. I want to get the missing values from 1 to 99.

![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lead()` to get the missing values in-between rows and `union all` to bring in the first one:

```
select serial_start + 1, next_ss - 1
from (select t.*,
             lead(serial_start) over (partition by year order by serial_start) as next_ss
      from t
      where year = 2020
     ) t
where next_ss is not null or next_ss <> ss + 1
union all
select 1, min(serial_start) - 1
from t
where year = 2020
group by year
having min(serial_start) <> 1;
```